# Configure HTTP Access Logging in WSO2 products Not working

Tags: logging, tomcat7, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 esb-4.8.1 I wish to see my server log which service is calling and what response time for service or request so I followed this bog [BLog for wso2 products](http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.in/2013/07/configure-access-logging-in-wso2.html)as per this blog it should work but its behaving different.
In tomcat server.xml file I have modified with remote host and its working fine.

```
<!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
     Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
<!--
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
-->

<!-- Access log processes all example.
     Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
     Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
       prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
       pattern="%h %l %T %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>
```

writing the information as per below

```
*.*.*.* - 6.769 - [14/Oct/2014:09:58:28 +0530] "POST /middleware/services/Test2Service HTTP/1.1" 200 787
*.*.*.* - 0.720 - [14/Oct/2014:09:58:30 +0530] "POST /middleware/services/audit2Service HTTP/1.1" 200 381
*.*.*.* - 0.086 - [14/Oct/2014:10:04:31 +0530] "POST /middleware/services/TestService HTTP/1.1" 200 787
*.*.*.* - 0.235 - [14/Oct/2014:10:04:32 +0530] "POST /middleware/services/audit3Service HTTP/1.1" 200 381
```

So i followed the same in wso2 i made changes in 
**HOME\repository\conf\tomcat\catlina-server.xml** like below I just changed the pattern like belowwhat i have done in tomcat 
**%h %l %T %u %t "%r" %s %b**
But its not printing every request message its just printing server login through the UI like below

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Oct/2014:16:15:20 +0530] "GET /carbon/log-admin/appenders-ajaxprocessor.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1152 "https://localhost:9443/carbon/log-admin/log-admin.jsp?region=region1&item=logging_menu&loginStatus=true" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Oct/2014:16:15:20 +0530] "GET /carbon/log-admin/js/loggingadmin.js?_=1413197120099 HTTP/1.1" 200 1199 "https://localhost:9443/carbon/log-admin/log-admin.jsp?region=region1&item=logging_menu&loginStatus=true" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Oct/2014:16:15:22 +0530] "GET /carbon/log-admin/loggers-ajaxprocessor.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 50412 "https://localhost:9443/carbon/log-admin/log-admin.jsp?region=region1&item=logging_menu&loginStatus=true" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36"
```

So what is the use of this i wish to get the per service request how would i achieve this my configuration is

```
<Host name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" deployOnStartup="false" autoDeploy="false" appBase="${carbon.home}/repository/deployment/server/webapps/">
          <Valve className="org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve"/>
          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="${carbon.home}/repository/logs"
               prefix="http_access_management_console_" suffix=".log"
               pattern="%h %l %T %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
          <Valve className="org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve" threshold="600"/>
          <Valve className="org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve"/>
      </Host>
```

So no use of above configuration how i am getting in tomcat in same way i wish to get the values I followed this link
[HTTP access log](http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.in/2013/07/configure-access-logging-in-wso2.html)

so how would i get this in tomcat its working wso2 log made on top of tomcat then why its not working i am wondering about this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in ESB 4.9.0 Release, please refer

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2598

For further details.